# Stripe tokenization

Tags: c#, api, token, stripe-payments

Sorry for the generic questions here but although I have read the whole Stripe API website multiple times, I still cannot understand the tokenization workflow.

I intend to use Stripe via a C# Windows Forms app and a C# website using the Stripe API.
I want to tokenize credit cards and then use the token to make charges to the cards (not only once).

I found that the only way to do this is to create Customer and use the Customer ID instead of the traditional token to do the charges.

Is it so?

If so, I found no way how to cancel the use of specific Customer IDs for charges. I want to keep active for no more than 2 weeks.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are correct that you need to attach the token to a customer in order to reuse the same payment source. See [this article](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards).

If you want to then make the source no longer chargeable after two weeks, you can [detach it](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/detach) from the customer.